# Причина возникновения Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, python, django

Есть такой скрипт в отдельном файле bookmarklet_launcher.js:

```
(function () {
  if (!window.bookmarklet) {
    var bookmarklet_js = document.body.appendChild(
      document.createElement("script")
    );
    bookmarklet_js.src =
      "//127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bookmarklet.js?r=" +
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999999999);
    window.bookmarklet = true;
  } else {
    bookmarkletLaunch();
  }
})();
```

Выдает вышеуказанную ошибку, если ссылаюсь на него таким путем:

```
<a href="javascript:{% include 'bookmarklet_launcher.js' %}"></a>
```

Но если вставляю скрипт напрямую:

```
<a href="javascript:(function () {
                if (!window.bookmarklet) {
                  var bookmarklet_js = document.body.appendChild(
                    document.createElement('script')
                  );
                  bookmarklet_js.src =
                    '//127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bookmarklet.js?r=' +
                    Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999999999);
                  window.bookmarklet = true;
                } else {
                  bookmarkletLaunch();
                }
              })();" class="button">Bookmark it</a>
```

То скрипт выполняется корректно. Почему?
Сервер разработки запускается с тестовым сертификатом следующим образом:

```
python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file cert.crt
```

Comment: Возможно ответ найдется в этой статье - https://thecode.media/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input/

Comment: У тебя в первом примере используются двойные кавычки, а в "правильном" примере одинарные... А у тега `a` всегда двойные кавычки. ;)

Comment: Пересмотрел код, и не понял где ошибка с кавычками. Можете подсказать в каком именно месте они стоят неправильно?

Comment: @Teslajke. в первом отрывке выглядит так - document.createElement("script"). А во втором так  document.createElement('script'). Измените в первом примере двойные кавычки на одинарные

Comment: Большое спасибо. Таким же путем поправил  и "//127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bookmarklet.js?r=" в первом примере. И теперь скрипт выполняется.